# App wont send confirmation Emails via Sendgrid and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid

I have been searching for a solution quite a while now but i haven't worked so far.

I want to setup devise so it can send confirmation mails via sendgrid on heroku. i configured a custom domain to my app, as well as to sendgrid which added a `em403.mydomain.com`. I will use "mydomain.com" for further explainations which i will replace in my actual app.

My Setup:

**environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port                 => 587,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :domain               => "em403.mydomain.com"
}
```

**initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.mailer_sender = 'hello@mydomain.com'
config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

config.reconfirmable = true
config.confirmation_keys = [:email]
```

**config/environment.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'em403.mydomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

i have no idea why it does not work, because i configured as described. what i have tried as well was following [this tutorial by sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/#configure-actionmailer-to-use-sendgrid) which is not considering devise as user auth. even though i tried to implement the controller settings into my custom `devise/registrations_controller`. before i forgot: i also added the api key into my heroku configuration.. do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check your secrets.yml doesn't have space somewhere, 
Check you .env parameters have been posted correctly,

Comment: what do you mean? i use the heroku config for the env parameters and applied the suggested ones by sendgrid and heroku